# How to fix a nonworking "echo" PHP search result link?

Tags: php, html

I will try to be more specific.

Search Results from an php/mysqli query are put into a table.

This is the code for the table:

```
    <tr>
       <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-right:7;" id="Photo1<?php echo $uid ?>">
          <a href="../view_profile/view_profile.php?id=<?php echo $uid; ?>">
             <img src="../../users/<?php echo $gender; ?>/<?php echo $email; ?>/Profile/<?php echo $img; ?>" style="height:70; width:70;">
          </a>
       </td>
       <td onMouseOver="serched_name_over1(<?php echo $uid;?>)" onMouseOut="serched_name_out1(<?php echo $uid;?>)" width="500" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="Name_bg1<?php echo $uid; ?>">
           <a href="../view_profile/view_profile.php?id=<?php echo $uid;?>" id="Name_font1<?php echo $uid;?>"><?php echo $name; ?>
           </a>
       </td>
   </tr>
```

I run the query and results are shown on website.

Source Code:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" border="0">

        <tr>

        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-right:7;" id="Photo156">
            <a href="../view_profile/view_profile.php?id=56">
                <img src="../../users/Male/jonnycash@gmail.com/Profile/GABRIEL ALCANTAR ALCALA.png" style="height:70; width:70;">
            </a>
            <a href="../view_profile/view_profile.php">
                <img src="../../users/Male/jonnycash@gmail.com/Profile/GABRIEL ALCANTAR ALCALA.png" style="height:70; width:70;">
            </a>
        </td>

        <td onMouseOver="serched_name_over1(56)" onMouseOut="serched_name_out1(56)" width="500" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" id="Name_bg156">
            <a href="../view_profile/view_profile.php?id=56"  id="Name_font156">
                Jonny Cash              </a>
        </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"> <hr style="border-color:#CCCCCC;"> </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Now, the info I want is shown on the website, however...

THE LINK  does not work on the website (i click on the img and nothing), but on the Source Code it does (i click on the link and it takes me to page).

I have tried echoing in parts to construct the path, but no use.  I tried   and also, nothing.  I tried using the htmlspecialchars and htmlentities.  And nothing.  I have even tried doing a regular html code inside the table along side the results... and nothing.  It does not link.

What am I doing wrong?

If you need to see more code, please let me know to attach more.

Please help.

Comment: You're missing `?id=56` in one of the links.

Comment: Are there supposed to be two links in the first `<td>`, or that a copying error? It's not in the PHP code.

Comment: The code you've shown looks fine, clicking on a link should just work. I suspect there's some JavaScript intercepting the click.

Comment: Barmar, yes, it was me trying other methods.

Comment: This looks fine to me as well. Have you looked at the devtools in your browser to determine if there are any errors or other unexpected behavior. (In chrome I would check both the console and maybe the network tabs).  Also, this is a bit of a long shot but I've had weird experiences like this where the img tag was handling the click and the event was not bubbling up to the the link. I would check to see if you have any global click handlers set in javascript for the img tag.

Comment: Thank you all.  Code was ok.  I had to start from scratch to find my error.  It was a css z-index that I did not post because I didn't think it would matter.. however, it did..  .   .   .  THANK YOU AGAIN!!!...